# Android Emulator keeps crashing

Tags: android, eclipse

I have already ran the application before but I have put new code into it and when I try to run it again I am getting the following message:

```
[2014-02-06 13:21:06 - newAndroidApplication] Failed to install newAndroidApplication.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

[2014-02-06 13:21:06 - newAndroidApplication] (null)
[2014-02-06 13:21:06 - newAndroidApplication] Launch canceled!
```

so could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: have you tried to restart it?

Comment: do you mean just close eclipse altogether or is there a way of restarting the entire avd?

Comment: the only emu needs to be restarted but if doesn't help then you need to restart the entire avd.

Comment: just the emulator (or both if you have time), it happened to me with my phone and disconnecting it and reconnecting solved the issue

Comment: how do I restart the entire avd?

Comment: try to run that app on emulator-5556

Comment: Try to use this : http://www.genymotion.com/    It's an Android emulator but it use the power of your computer and work better than the avd !!